# openstack specific host vm launch

Tags: host, openstack

everyone!

I'm running openstack (devstack installed) on 4 compute nodes & 1 control node cluster.

Compute hosts: node1, node2, node3, node4.

How can I run VM(s) on specific host(s), for instance on node3?

Using horizon or euca-* tools.

Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

Select a specific node to boot instances on:  
http://docs.openstack.org/essex/openstack-compute/admin/content/specify-host-to-boot-instances-on.html

Admin account required 
Essex version

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the availability zone -z option in euca-run-instances. For example if you wanted to boot the same image on every compute host that you have.

```
HOSTS=`nova-manage service list | grep compute | grep -v XXX | grep -v disabled | sort | cut -f1 -d' '`

for host in $HOSTS; do
    euca-run-instances -k my-keypair -z nova:$host my-ami-id
done
```

This little script assumes that you only have one "availability zone" called 'nova' (the default in devstack).

Note that this still works in Essex but only if you're the **admin** user.

Comment: Does that work with `nova boot --availability_zone nova:$host` as well?

Comment: Thanx all. Unfortunately this does not work: nova boot --image 1 --flavor 2 --key_name test --hint force_hosts=server2 my-server [link](http://docs.openstack.org/essex/openstack-compute/admin/content/specify-host-to-boot-instances-on.html)

Answer (score -2):

You can check your availability zone using:

```
openstack availability zone list
```

Now to create an instance on node2 you gave:

```
nova boot --flavor 'm1.tiny' --image (image id) --nic net-id=(network id) --availability-zone nova:node2 instance_name
```